# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when trying to run camus

Tags: java, exception, hadoop, camus

I downloaded the confluent package which includes camus jars and I followed the instructions online [enter link description here](http://confluent.io/docs/current/camus/docs/intro.html).

Hadoop is properly setup (meaning I can use hadoop fs -ls commands and other hadoop jar commands). However, when i tried to run

```
hadoop jar confluent-camus-1.0.jar com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.CamusJob
```

I got "main" classNotFound error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.linkedin.camus.
etl.kafka.CamusJob
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:205)
```

The the path to the "confluent-camus-1.0.jar" is correct (right under the folder). I didn't start the kafka service, just to try to run it.

Anyone got similar problems?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you miss some jars inn your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to inspect your jar file:

```
jar tvf confluent-camus-1.0.jar | grep com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.CamusJob
```

If you do not find this class, try to find it in other jar, which generated by camus.

After you should add target jar with

```
hadoop jar confluent-camus-1.0.jar com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.CamusJob -libjars {JAR_NAME}
```